# Bootstrap's modal.toggle is not working in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I wanted to toggle modal after a promise is resolved, which is triggered on button click. As per official doc `modal.toggle()` should do the magic but it is not working. I am using bootstrap's version 5.2.2. I can't use react-bootstrap.

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";

const ExampleModal = () => {
  const toggleModal = () => {
    const myModalEl = document.getElementById('exampleModalToggle')
    const modal = new Modal(myModalEl);
    modal.toggle();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModalToggle"
        aria-hidden="true"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel"
        tabindex="-1"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h1 className="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">
                Modal 1
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                onClick={toggleModal}
                className="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2"
                // data-bs-toggle="modal" // wanted to toggle after a promise is resolved
              >
                Open second modal
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModalToggle2"
        aria-hidden="true"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2"
        tabindex="-1"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h1 className="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">
                Modal 2
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Hide this modal and show the first with the button below.
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
              >
                Back to first
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        href="#exampleModalToggle"
        role="button"
      >
        Open first modal
      </a>
    </>
  );
};

export default ExampleModal;
```

I have prepared above sample code and ran this code on sandbox. This is also unable to toggle the modal. Also the background shadow is getting darker after each button click. This is same behaviour i am experiencing in my project.

Comment: You're creating a new modal instance every time the function is called, which probably isn't what you want. Besides that, please do not use the document object. **You're writing React!!** If you must at least use [`ref`](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useRef).

Comment: Thanks @code. You were correct, a new model instance was getting created. After using Modal.getInstance it worked. i will share the updated code with your improvement suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code which worked for me.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";

const ExampleModal = () => {
  const myModalEl1 = useRef(null);
  const myModalEl2 = useRef(null);
  const toggleModal = () => {
    // const myModalEl1 = document.getElementById("exampleModalToggle");
    const modal = Modal.getInstance(myModalEl1.current, {});
    modal.toggle();
    // const myModalEl2 = document.getElementById("exampleModalToggle2");
    const modal2 = Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModalEl2.current, {});
    modal2.toggle();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModalToggle"
        ref={myModalEl1}
        aria-hidden="true"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel"
        tabindex="-1"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h1 className="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">
                Modal 1
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                onClick={toggleModal}
                className="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2"
                // data-bs-toggle="modal" // wanted to toggle after a promise is resolved
              >
                Open second modal
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModalToggle2"
        aria-hidden="true"
        ref={myModalEl2}
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2"
        tabindex="-1"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h1 className="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">
                Modal 2
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Hide this modal and show the first with the button below.
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
              >
                Back to first
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        href="#exampleModalToggle"
        role="button"
      >
        Open first modal
      </a>
    </>
  );
};

export default ExampleModal;
```